# Unable to Remove Pending Changes in TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment

We had an issue recently that caused TeamCity to stop running builds for several hours. The result was a large queue of pending changes. Now this has been resolved, and new changes are going through the pipeline with no problem.

However, the `pending changes` area still shows 43 pending. All of these changes have been included in subsequent commits, and have therefore been built. Why is TeamCity showing these old commits as pending? And how do I clear the queue?

[image: TeamCity Pending Changes Queue]

Comment: Is this build step dependent on other build steps? Also check that in the VCS root for the build configuration if the "Show changes from snapshot dependencies" is checked

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: No, unfortunately. And the problem has only gotten worse now that the team has switched to a feature branch approach. Only the final pull request gets built on TeamCity, so any commits leading up to that are displayed indefinitely in 'Pending Changes' and we have no way to clear it. We have hundreds now and everyone just ignores it. Not an ideal solution but that's where we are.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue and found a way to work around it. Not ideal but worked for me.

Select your project. Click on Edit Configuration Settings. Select Actions and Copy. Create a duplicate copy of your project. 
Now go through the process again only delete the old project instead of copying it.

This gives you a new project with the same setup and none of the history or pending items of the old one. Like I said not ideal, but will get rid of the pending items.